# HSQLDB not saving updates made through Java

Tags: java, hsqldb

I am trying to add records to a table in an HSQL database through Java.

I have an HSQL database I made through OpenOffice, renamed the .odb file to .zip and extracted the SCRIPT and PROPERTIES files (It has no data in it at the moment) to a folder "\database" in my java project folder.

The table looks like this in the SCRIPT file

```
CREATE CACHED TABLE PUBLIC."Season"("SeasonID" INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY(START WITH 0) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,"Year" VARCHAR(50))
```

All fine so far, the database connects just fine in Java with this code:

```
public void connect(){
    try{
        String dbName = "database\\db";

        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:file:" + dbName, // filenames prefix
                "sa", // user
                "");  // pass

    }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I have the following code to insert a record into "Season".

```
public void addSeason(String year){

        int result = 0;

        try { 
            stmt = con.createStatement(); 
            result = stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO \"Season\"(\"Year\") VALUES ('" + year + "')"); 
            con.commit(); 
            stmt.close();
        }catch (Exception e) { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        } 

        System.out.println(result + " rows affected");
}
```

I have a final function called printTables():

```
private void printTables(){
    try { 
        stmt = con.createStatement(); 
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM \"Season\"");
        System.out.println("SeasonID\tYear");
        while(rs.next()){
            System.out.println(rs.getInt("SeasonID") + "\t\t" + rs.getString("Year"));
        }
    }catch (Exception e) { 
        e.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }
}
```

Now if I run this sequence of functions:

```
connect();
printTables();
addSeason("2010");
printTables();
```

I get this output:

```
SeasonID    Year
1 rows affected
SeasonID    Year
0       2010
```

Now when I close the program and start it again I get exactly the same output. So the change made during the first run hasn't been saved to the database. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Remove conn.commit() since you're in auto commit mode and see what happens (the updates will be committed implicitly). Alternatively, set setAutoCommit(boolean) to false to enable transactions but then you must use conn.commit to make the changes persistent (in this case you'll want to add conn.rollback in your catch block.

Comment: You should also close your ResultSet, not just the Statement.

Comment: Thanks, I'd read somewhere that statement.close() also closes any open ResultSets. I removed the commits but still the same problem...

Comment: Also setting auto commit to false and committing

Comment: Weirdly I tried addSeason("2010"); con.close(); and this works, but if I try to incorporate con.close() as a finally clause in the addSeason function it doesn't work...

Answer (score 1):

It's caused by write delay params in hsqldb, by default has 500ms delay synch from memory to files.

So problem is solved when it's set to false

`statement.execute("SET FILES WRITE DELAY FALSE");`

or set as you like based on your app behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

So my workaround is to close the connection after every update, then open a new connection any time I want to do something else.

This is pretty unsatisfactory and i'm sure it will cause problems later on if I want to perform queries mid-update. Also it's a time waster.

If I could find a way to ensure that con.close() was called whenever the program was killed that would be fine...